# Evaluating $\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{(-5)^n}{8^{2 n}}$ making use of geometric series

Tags: calculus

> Evaluate
>   $$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-5)^n}{8^{2n}}$$
>   using geometric series.

I thought it would be possible to split this series such that we have

$$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } (-5)^n \cdot \sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^{2 n}$$

However, I am not sure that this is actually possible and I also see that the first sum does not converge, so even if it was possible I am not able to solve it. Could someone walk me through the steps?

Comment: No, it's not. But note $(-5)^n/ 8^{2n}=  (-5/8^2)^n$.

Comment: it is a good idea to write out the first few terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that
$$
\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{(-5)^n}{8^{2 n}}= \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty } \left(-\frac{5}{64}\right)^n
$$

Now let's look at the first two terms of the sum
$$
\left(-\frac{5}{64}\right)^2+ \left(-\frac{5}{64}\right)^3+\dots
$$
$$
=\left(\frac{5}{64}\right)^2- \left(\frac{5}{64}\right)^3+\dots
$$

So now we know that
$$
a= \left(\frac{5}{64}\right)^2=\frac{25}{4096}
$$
And 
$$
r= -\frac{5}{64}
$$
Therefore 
$$
\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty } \left(-\frac{5}{64}\right)^n=\frac{\frac{25}{4096}}{1-\left(-\frac{5}{64}\right)}=\frac{25}{4416}
$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: It is $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{-5}{64}\right)^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Try $$\displaystyle \sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \left(-\frac{5}{64}\right)^n = \frac{25}{4096}\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left(-\frac{5}{64}\right)^n$$ as a typical geometric series

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, no. But since $8^{2n} = 64^n$, you can rewrite your series as
$$
\sum \left(\frac{-5}{64}\right)^n,
$$
which should get you on your way.

Comment: Could you not evaluate it first using the fact that $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-5}{64}\right)^n=\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{-5}{64}\right)}$$ and the subtracting the first two terms from that fraction, since $n=0$ and $n=1$ are not included in the bounds, then simplify?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. Alternatively, you could let $a = -5/64$, and call your sum $S$, and note that $\frac{S}{a^2}$ is the sum from $0$ to infinity, so that $S$ must be $a^2$ times that sum. In general, $\sum_0 c r^n = \frac{c}{1 - r}$ lets you handle sums starting at nonzero values (like the "2" in your problem) by factoring out some power of $r$ and including that in $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{-5}{64}\right)^n$$